# SSIS: DTS LogProvider could not find text file

Tags: ssis

I have multiple batch scripts that execute corresponding SSIS packages.

Each script has pretty much the same content in it with the exception of package name and log file name.

Each package is created within the same directory.

Contents of batch file:

```
echo Running ISR FTP
dtexec.exe /f "Z:\Projects\SSIS\FTP_ISR.dtsx" /L "DTS.LogProviderTextFile;C:\Data\logs\ftp_isr.txt"
```

If I have the below bat files. Packages 1, 2 and 3 run successfully from the batch files and generate the corresponding log files. All the batch files are created with the exact same script. All 4 packages are distinct in their functionality just the mode of execution is same.

However ftp_isr.bat fails with DTSLogProvider: Could not find connection error message.

```
 Package1.bat
 Package2.bat
 Package3.bat
 ftp_isr.bat
```

Error message:

```
 Error: 2018-09-04 14:05:55.12
 Code: 0xC02020EA
 Source: FTP_ISR Log provider "{6B9ACBB8-AB63-462F-A692-BC7C18FD695C}"
 Description: The connection manager "C:\Data\logs\ftp_isr.tx
 t" is not found. A component failed to find the connection manager in the 
 Connections collection.
 End Error
```

I ran the package in SSIS and it runs successfully. Log file exists in directory.

Project connection with corresponding log file exists. Replacing /L with /l and vice-versa has no luck.

Any other thoughts on what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Open the package and go to the logs sub menu. Do you see a connection to the file ftp_isr.txt? Most probably someone removed it and forgot to update the connection string.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, that connection exists and is valid. That is the reason why this error is puzzling.

Comment: Your output clearly states that it is missing the connection manager with the UID {6B9ACBB8-AB63-462F-A692-BC7C18FD695C}